# which is better to use the EntityFramework or ADO.net

Tags: entity-framework-4, ado.net

im going to create a new website , this is the first time for me and im confused about using ADO.net or EntityFrameWork , can anyone help me about which is better to use and the advantages of each one

Answer (score 2):

This dudes blog has a nice insight about entity framework and a kind of comparison from his own experiences about Entity Framework vs traditional ADO.Net... [why use the entity framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2008/05/17/why-use-the-entity-framework.aspx)

I'm currently working on a project converting a multitude of ADO.Net strongly typed Datasets to Entity Framework 4 and I can see all of what he says is true, and more... EF is seemingly well supported and will not wither and die like some of Microsoft's other technologies, as said above it is simply a wrapper around ADO.Net which gives you a layer of abstraction that has many benefits, the main draw back being that Linq to SQL is more fully developed than Linq to Entities which can be a pain sometimes, although there is always a way to achieve what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework is a wrapper around ADO.Net and provides a simpler way to access your database. In most situations I would recommend using EF over raw ADO.net but in the case where you need bulk operation performance you may decide not to use EF.